# Is there any different between "Bring your kit/stuff/tools/equipment"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Could you explain do we have any different between [Kit,stuff,tool,equipment].

• For example if I want to use them in this sentence, What will change about the meaning of sentence?

> Bring your kit.

&

> Bring your stuff.

&

> Bring your tools.

&

> Bring your equipment.

Comment: Instead of asking what the difference is between your 4 suggestions (virtually impossible without an exact context), why don't you tell us exactly what *your* context is, and we'll tell you which of those words (or perhaps some *other* word) is most suitable?

Comment: What is your understanding of how they differ, of when or how one might be more appropriate than another? In what context are you encountering them, or trying to use them?

Comment: _Tools_ has a very specific meaning, _kit_ may or may not include clothing, _stuff_ is very vague...

Comment: Kit and equipment are close synonyms. Kit has a military or camping association, however, while equipment is more generic. Tools are a subset of equipment. Stuff could be any tangible personal property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stuff" is a very general and informal word. You wouldn't use it in formal instructions. "Bring your stuff" is something that might be said in casual conversation.

"Kit" means a specific, designated set of items. If you said, "Bring your kit", the listener would understand you to mean a set of items that he had been given for this purpose, or that he was told to gather together. We'd expect everyone to have essentially the same kit. Or at least, that there would be groups with each having their own kit, like if you were talking about a group of medical personnel, there might be a "nurse's kit" and a "surgeon's kit" and an "anesthesiologist's kit", etc.

"Equipment" is more general. Each person might have their own equipment. Equipment is generally understood to mean tools or mechanical or electronic devices. For example, for a team of archaeologists, picks and shovels might be "equipment". Their clothes and personal items would not be.